# How to fix backtrace Mediawiki errors with PuTTY?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, putty

On attempting to create a database for my second wiki, I had problems with setting up a separate database. I first got an Access Denied error,m and then I got a database query error. I have been using PuTTY to fix the backtrace errors, but it didn't show a message while doing the commands given on another thread. How can I fix database query errors using PuTTY? The query error looked like this:

Query:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name,
user_real_name, user_email, user_touched, user_token, user_email_authenticated, user_email_token, user_email_token_expires, user_registration, user_editcount FROM gjlxrtap_mw19758.mwd50q_user WHERE user_id = '1' LIMIT 1 Function:

User::loadFromDatabase

Error:

1142 SELECT command denied to user 'gjlxrtap_wiki2'@'localhost' for table 'mwd50q_user' (localhost)

Backtrace:

0 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(979): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)
1 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1343): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)
2 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1411): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select(string, array, array, string, array, array)
3 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(1287): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectRow(string, array, array, string, array)
4 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(496): User->loadFromDatabase(integer)
5 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(892): User->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)
6 [internal function]: WANObjectCache->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL)
7 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1012): call_user_func_array(Closure, array)
8 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(898): WANObjectCache->doGetWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array, NULL)
9 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(521): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array)
10 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(441): User->loadFromCache()
11 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/user/User.php(405): User->loadFromId(integer)
12 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/UserInfo.php(88): User->load()
13 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/CookieSessionProvider.php(119): MediaWiki\Session\UserInfo::newFromId(string)
14 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(487): MediaWiki\Session\CookieSessionProvider->provideSessionInfo(WebRequest)
15 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(190): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionInfoForRequest(WebRequest)
16 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebRequest.php(735): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionForRequest(WebRequest)
17 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/session/SessionManager.php(129): WebRequest->getSession()
18 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/Setup.php(762): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::getGlobalSession()
19 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/WebStart.php(114): require_once(string)
20 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/index.php(40): require(string)
21 {main}
```

Comment: `SELECT command denied to user 'gjlxrtap_wiki2'@'localhost' for table 'mwd50q_user' ` is referring to a permissions issue. Go into the database and check the granted permissions (`show grants for gjlxrtap_wiki2;`) and the grant the permissions you need. Most likely this is a new user which you created recently in the database but didn't assign any grants

Comment: How do I do this in PhpMyAdmin? In PhpMyAdmin, the following setting tabs are: Structure, SQL, Search, Query Import, Export, Operations, Routines, Events, Triggers, and Designs. I did it in SQL, and it gave me the following error: #1044 - Access denied for user 'gjlxrtap'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: not familiar with PhpMyAdmin as I usually go about my databases from the console. This should be done in the same place where you created the `gjlxrtap_wiki2` mysql user. If you did it on PhpMyAdmin, there should be a place to manage permissions/grants. If there isn't, you should have at least one mysql user (root or another power user) with enough privileges to perform a `GRANT`

Comment: I started another database from scratch. Now it shows this message: (Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'gjlxrtap_wiki2point1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (localhost))

Comment: This is definitely a privileges problem, not a database one... Do you have full administrative access to your db or just what your hosting vendor gave you?

Comment: I only have what the hosting vendor gave me. I checked off all permissions for my database user, and I still get the same Access Denied message. How do I do this with PhpMyAdmin and MySQL databases?